# Error in linking files into a kernel

Tags: c++, assembly, linker, operating-system, kernel

I have problem. I have compiled file boot.o:

```
[BITS 16]   
[ORG 0x7C00]
[global start]
[extern _main]
start:
call _main
cli 
hlt
```

and compiled C++ file main.o:

```
 int main(){
//processes
}
```

Im using this LD file linker.ld for linking:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("binary")
ENTRY(start)
SECTIONS
{
. = 0x100000;

.text ALIGN(4096) :
{
    *(.text*)
    *(.gnu.linkonce.t*)
}

.rodata ALIGN(4096) :
{
    start_ctors = .;
    *(.ctor*)
    end_ctors = .;

    start_dtors = .;
    *(.dtor*)
    end_dtors = .;

    *(.rodata*)
    *(.gnu.linkonce.r*)
}

.data ALIGN(4096) :
{
    *(.data*)
    *(.gnu.linkonce.d*)
}

.bss ALIGN(4096) :
{
    *(.COMMON*)
    *(.bss*)
    *(.gnu.linkonce.b*)
}
```

}
So I want to start linking and I'm using g++ for windows, and I'm using this commands in cmd: `ld -T linker.ld -o kernle.bin main.o boot.o`. And is rejecting me error: `ld: cannot preform PE operations on non PE output file kernel.bin`. Does anybody know how can I repair it? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe -oformat bin?

And I doubt you will be able to boot it, anyway... Go read some bootloader tutorials (on osdev.org and brokenthorn.com) and you will get an answer why.

Comment: You will never get your c++ kernel to fit in 512 bytes (a bootsector), you will not be able to run it in 16bit real mode (in which processor work at boot) and so on. I suggest reading [Getting started](http://wiki.osdev.org/Getting_Started), [Boot sequence](http://wiki.osdev.org/Boot_sequence) and [Bootloader](http://wiki.osdev.org/Bootloader) articles at osdev.org wiki (to begin with...).

Answer (score 0):

You are using a compiler and toolchain built to make windows executables, not flat binaries. You need a cross compiler for kernel development. Also, you will need a bootloader, a kernel, even minimal, can't fit into the 512 byte bootsector.
Correct me if I'm wrong, but you don't seem to understand the bot process of a pc at all. I suggest reading http://wiki.osdev.org/ as a start.